# Build BigBlueButton from dockerfile

Tags: docker, bigbluebutton

I want to build BigBlueButton system from the Dockerfiles.

I have tried some times with exist Dockerfiles in source code, but it have not succeeded.

I found many BigBlueButton components in source code, but I don't know the order for building components.

This is the source link and I have listed some components that have Dockerfiles.

https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/

1. akka-bbb-apps
2. akka-bbb-fsesl
3. bbb-common-message
4. bbb-common-web
5. bbb-fsesl-client
6. bbb-libreoffice
7. bbb-lti
8. bbb-webhooks
9. bigbluebutton-html5
10. bigbluebutton-web

What is the first packet had to build? And what is the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good resource is the lab [build for kubernettes](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/tree/develop/labs/docker) which has a lot of information for how to build the bbb modules.
From the labs directory in the main source from [makefile](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/blob/develop/labs/docker/Makefile) I would try the following order
`bbb-common-message, bbb-common-web, bbb-fsesl-client, akka-bbb-apps, akka-bbb-fsesl, bigbluebutton-web, bigbluebutton-html5, bbb-webrtc-sfu, bbb-webhooks`

You will need all the build dependencies to be installed like sbt for the scala modules.

If you just want to work on the html5 client or custom integrations then the [docker-dev](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/docker-dev) is a good option, not least as it sets up nginx with certs so you can develop locally with https.

I would suggest setting up the `docker-dev` to get insight on how the modules interact if you are not familiar with the bbb architecture.